# On Jenkins, Sonar post job MAVEN_OPTS doesn't seem to work

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jvm-arguments

On a particular Jenkins job, i need to configure the JVM PermSize and MaxPermSize for the Maven execution launched by Sonar.

I'll try different combinations that didn't work, mainly the MAVEN_OPTS fields, both on the main Jenkins build and on the Sonar post-job configuration.

The command-line displayed in the job log concerning Sonar is :

```
"D:\Program Files\<some-project>\pom.xml" -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver "-Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8" ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://<some-host>/sonar
```

So, no JVM options set. For the record, my wanted options are :

```
-XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Environnement:

- Windows 2008
- Jenkins 1.554.3
- Maven 3.0.3
- Sonar 3.7
- Sonar Jenkins Plugin : 2.1

Thank you !

Comment: Please update maven to at least 3.0.5 as soon as possible, cause 3.0.3 has many bugs...BTW: Have you tried to do the sonar upload via command line ? And what exactly does not work? Error messages log files?

Answer (score 0):

For the unitary tests for example, Maven forked the Java process and the JVM options set with MAVEN_OPTS are not taken into account.

Maybe it's the same for the Sonar analysis.

If you are using a Maven profile to launch your Sonar analysis, can you check if you can set the JMV options in the `<argLine>` section?